# adding metadata to tensorflow tflearn CNN

Tags: tensorflow, metadata, conv-neural-network

I built a simple CNN network for (medical) image classification successfully, using tflearn.  When I tried to add metadata to the CNN, I ran into this problem:ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (96, 2) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(1390, 2)'. Any help is appreciated:

```
#extract pictures (0 thru 4095), next two bytes for the selection, and the rest for metadata
X, Y, Z  = train_data[:,0:4096],train_data[:,4096:4098], train_data[:,4098:]
X = X.reshape([-1,64,64,1])


network = input_data(shape=[None, 64, 64, 1])
mdnetwork = input_data(shape=[None, 100])
network = conv_2d(network, 30, 3, activation='relu')
network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
network = conv_2d(network, 30, 3, activation='relu')
network = conv_2d(network, 40, 3, activation='relu')
network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
network = conv_2d(network, 40, 3, activation='relu')
network = conv_2d(network, 40, 3, activation='relu')
network = conv_2d(network, 30, 3, activation='relu')
network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
network = fully_connected(network, 100, activation='relu')

Zt= fully_connected(Z, 100, activation='relu')
network = merge([network,Zt], 'concat')

network = dropout(network, 0.5)
network = fully_connected(network, 50, activation='relu')
network = fully_connected(network, 2, activation='softmax')

# Train using classifier
network = regression(network, optimizer='adam',
                 loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                 learning_rate=0.001)

model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=3)

model.fit([np.array(X).reshape(-1, 64, 64, 1), np.array(Z).reshape(-1, 100)], Y, n_epoch=5, shuffle=True, validation_set=0,
    show_metric=True, batch_size=96, run_id='my_cnn')

model.save('my_cnn.tflearn')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good I can answer my question here! Anyway, I found the issue in my code above. It was a simple error.  The error message led me astray.  Here is the solution: Replace this code snippet

```
Zt= fully_connected(Z, 100, activation='relu')
network = merge([network,Zt], 'concat')
```

with

```
network = merge([network, mdnetwork], 'concat')
```

Thanks for those who read my request.  Let me know if there are other options.